# Notarizing Electron application with Finder Sync extension

Tags: macos, electron, code-signing

I'm working on an Electron app, with Finder Sync extension.

When application is code-signed, but not notarized, everything works excelent. When I add the notarization process, no errors or warnings are shown during the process, but the extension does not start at all.

What exaclty are the requirements, when distributing extensions within app, so that the extension works after notarization?

What I have done/tried so far:
 - The .appex file is added to the PlugIns folder in build process
 - Tried code-signing the .appex before the build, then notarizing, but extexsion still does not start.
 - Tried force code-signing it in the build process.
 - Even tried not signing it at ll -> Notarization passed with no issues. Still .appex not running.
 - Hardened runtime is enabled.

Questions:
 - What actually should be the extension AppID? Apple documentation for Finder Sync Extension says "Be sure to use the same identifier for both the Finder Sync extension and the containing app" but in a notarization document it said they should be the same?
 - Is it the fact that I'm not adding app group that's breaking it? When not notarized, this does not seem to be a problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be linked to Electron's use of private APIs, as noted [here](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/11/05/apple_app_store_electron/)

Comment: @TheDarkKnight We are not distributing the app through the App Store.

Comment: Yes, you stated that in the question. I'm referring to the fact that you shouldn't be surprised if Apple's Notorization flags up usage of private frameworks too, which may cause it to fail. Note that in they turned down the severity of items that would cause notorization to fail and are due to turn it back up this month.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?

Comment: @jtbandes not yet.

Comment: FWIW, I solved some of my notarization issues by (1) enabling Hardened Runtime, and (2) making sure the extension was signed with the same Developer ID Application certificate that I was using to sign the whole app: https://github.com/foxglove/studio/pull/1270